# How does mobile safari process pdf so it can provide a search feature?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, pdf, uiwebview

I'm looking for a way to search and highlight in PDF in a uiwebview. I've seen quite a lot of topics about that but it's all using Core graphics. As far as my knowledge goes, the UIWebView render the PDFs as images. If that's the case, I'm wondering how does safari provides the search and highlight feature?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't the UIWebView use core graphics? Everything else in UIKit does and as you mentioned it has been done with core graphics.

Comment: Ok, so in the app, I have a document viewer that provides drawing tools inside a UIWebView (which is used to display other document types) So let's say instead of just simply feed the url of my pdf to my uiwebview, I draw it using core graphic, would it be possible to draw it inside the uiwebview to keep my current drawing system functional (mostly the coordinates, cause it's already live and used for several months by our users, and also synced to our web version of the platform) ?

Comment: I don't know about safari but here is an example of mozilla and dome app for integrate it with objective-c https://github.com/Jageen/PDFSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Safari (or, more specifically, Safari's PDF plugin) uses an Apple API called Search Kit. [NSHipster has an article on it here.](http://nshipster.com/search-kit/)

Unfortunately Search Kit has not yet been ported to iOS. For the search algorithm, then, you have a few options:

- Index your PDF's text using [S4LuceneLibrary](https://github.com/mikekppp/S4LuceneLibrary).
- Use Core Data as described in the WWDC 2010 video 'Mastering Core Data' to index and search the text.

For highlighting the text, you could

- Redraw the PDF's text using Core Text.
- Use UIWebView and HTML/CSS to draw the text (which also makes it easily searchable. I've done this myself.)

Depending on what interests you, let me know and I'd be happy to explain further.

EDIT 1: To draw the text and keep the layout in tact as much as possible, I would look into using something like [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). From there, you can employ a javascript framework like [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to take care of the actual highlighting (specifically, [this sample code](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html)). I've used Rangy for this purpose and have found it quite effective.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll take a look into using core data to search inside my PDF, as for drawing the text with the results highlighted, the second options seems best for my situation, but would that solution keep the format, images and layout of the file intact? If so, yes, I'd like to learn more about that.

Comment: I've edited my answer to detail a bit more about what using a UIWebView might entail.